# Using triggers to choose between two stack layouts on condition in Xamarin forms not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, triggers, datatrigger

I have two stack layouts inside a **Listview**. I want to show each of them at a time according to a condition. Here, there is a value called **Complete** When it's False, the lab results should be shown. when it's true the Document List Should be shown. This doesn't work. How to achieve that?

```xml
<StackLayout x:Name="LabLayout" IsVisible="False" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="Start" Spacing="0" Margin="0,-6,0,0">
    <StackLayout.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding Completed}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="StackLayout.IsVisible" Value="False"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout"  Binding="{Binding Completed}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="StackLayout.IsVisible" Value="True"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </StackLayout.Triggers>
    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"  TextColor="{StaticResource DarkColor}" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize17}"/>
    <Label Text="{Binding Author}" TextColor="{StaticResource QuateneryLightColor}" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize13}"/>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="{Binding LabItemStatus }" TextColor="{StaticResource QuateneryLightColor}" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize13}"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Progress}" TextColor="{StaticResource QuateneryLightColor}" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize13}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>


<StackLayout x:Name="DocumentLayout" IsVisible="False" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="Start" Spacing="0" Margin="0,-6,0,0">
    <StackLayout.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding Completed}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="StackLayout.IsVisible" Value="False"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout"  Binding="{Binding Completed}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="StackLayout.IsVisible" Value="True"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </StackLayout.Triggers>
    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="{StaticResource DarkColor}" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize17}"/>
    <Label Text="{Binding DateTimeString}" TextColor="{StaticResource QuateneryLightColor}" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize13}"/>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="{Binding Department }" TextColor="{StaticResource DarkColor}" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize13}"/>
        <Label Text="||" TextColor="{StaticResource DarkColor}" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize13}"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Author}" TextColor="{StaticResource DarkColor}" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize13}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use separate binding for each layout. like

```
<StackLayout x:Name="LabLayout" IsVisible="{Binding LabLayoutVisibility}" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="Start" Spacing="0" Margin="0,-6,0,0">
    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"  TextColor="{StaticResource DarkColor}" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize17}"/>
    <Label Text="{Binding Author}" TextColor="{StaticResource QuateneryLightColor}" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize13}"/>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="{Binding LabItemStatus }" TextColor="{StaticResource QuateneryLightColor}" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize13}"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Progress}" TextColor="{StaticResource QuateneryLightColor}" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize13}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>


<StackLayout x:Name="DocumentLayout" IsVisible="{Binding DocumentLayoutVisibility}" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="Start" Spacing="0" Margin="0,-6,0,0">
    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="{StaticResource DarkColor}" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize17}"/>
    <Label Text="{Binding DateTimeString}" TextColor="{StaticResource QuateneryLightColor}" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize13}"/>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="{Binding Department }" TextColor="{StaticResource DarkColor}" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize13}"/>
        <Label Text="||" TextColor="{StaticResource DarkColor}" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize13}"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Author}" TextColor="{StaticResource DarkColor}" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize13}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Isn't it better to create an IValueConverter that inverses a boolean value so you can bind both to the same property?

Comment: @Knoop yes. it is better.

Answer (score 0):

`IValueConverter` is designed for converting value between different types , here you could create a new variable as a as opposite to `Completed` ,and  binding it to `StackLayout.IsVisible`

```
    private bool completed;
    public bool Completed {
        get
        {
            return completed;
        }
        set {
            completed = value;
            UnCompleted= !completed;
            OnPropertyChanged("Completed");
        }
    }


    public bool UnCompleted
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

<StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding UnCompleted}">
```